# How to load a view in backbone correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I have the following backbone.js script. Traditionally I was rendering the view by using:

> var myItem = new Item();
>
> myItem.fetch(); var reward_view = new ListView({model:myItem});
>   reward_view.render();

However, most of the [examples](http://arturadib.com/hello-backbonejs/docs/3.html) I have seen don't do this and somehow allow you to load/init the view by using using:

```
var listView = new ListView();
```

**How?** This is what I have tried:

```
(function($){

   var Item = Backbone.Model.extend({
        urlRoot: '/api/v1/1/'
    });


  var List = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: Item
  });


  var ListView = Backbone.View.extend({

    el: '#reward_view',

       initialize: function(){
      _.bindAll(this, 'render'); // every function that uses 'this' as the current object should be in here

      this.collection = new List();
      this.render();

    },

     render: function(){
         console.log(this)
      $(this.el).html('<h1>Hello' + this.model.get('name') + '</h1>');
      return this; // for chainable calls, like .render().el
    }


  });
```

Comment: You need to bind the model or collection. You are almost there tho.